# For Loop in R for reading and exporting tiff file

Tags: r, loops, csv, tiff

I have multiple CSVs as inputs which basically have lat long info and i am exporting the .tiff images which have these lat longs plotted on a map. I want to some how loop this process so as I can read multiple CSVs and hence generate multiple maps(.tiff) corresponding to these CSVs.Any help will be appreciated !!

Here is the code which I am using at present

```
rm(list=ls())


sclusters_1 <- readLines("C:\\Users\\D85_H.csv")
skip_second <- sclusters_1[-2]
sclusters   <- read.csv(textConnection(skip_second), header = TRUE) 



library(grDevices)
library(PBSmapping)
library(maptools)
library(sp)

myShapeFile<-importShapefile("C:\\Users\\st99_d00_shp\\st99_d00",readDBF=TRUE, projection = "LL")
ConvUS <- convUL(myShapeFile)


addressEvents<-as.PolyData(sclusters,projection="LL", zone = 15)    
uaddressEvents <- convUL(addressEvents)
sclusters_cl <- unique(sclusters$PID)
len <- length(sclusters_cl)



palette(c("dodgerblue3","red3","olivedrab","purple4","turquoise2","orange3","lightskyblue4","mediumorchid3","saddlebrown","skyblue4"))

setwd("C:/Users/")
name, leave .tiff extension
tiff(filename = "Test.tiff",
          width = 3750, height = 3142, units = "px", pointsize = 12,
         compression = "lzw",
          bg = "transparent")



plotMap(ConvUS ,  xlim=c(-8000,3500), ylim=c(2000,9500), plt=c(0.07,0.97,0.07,0.98), bg = "white", border = "darkgrey", axes=FALSE, xlab=" ",ylab=" ", lty = 1, lwd = 2)

addPoints(uaddressEvents,col=1:len,cex=2.5, pch = "O") 


legend("topright",legend = sclusters_cl, cex=0.7, fill=palette())

#close output file stream
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, this is untested:

Since both the import and export filenames are passed as length-1 characters vectors, you can make a matrix like `m <- matrix(c("infile1.csv", "outfile1.tiff", "infile2.csv", "outfile2.tiff"),nrow=2)`.

Then you can just wrap the entire thing in a `for` loop over the columns of that matrix, e.g. `for(j in 1:ncol(m))`. Then just replace `"C:\\Users\\st99_d00_shp\\st99_d00"` with `m[1,j]` and `"Test.tiff"` with `m[2,j]`.

Even better practice might be to wrap the entire thing in a *function* and then write a separate loop that just calls the function. For example:

```
myTIFF <- function (infile, outfile) {
  # stuff you want to do to each pair of input and output files
}

m <- matrix(c(
              "infile1.csv", "outfile1.tiff",
              "infile2.csv", "outfile2.tiff"
              # and so on
             ), nrow = 2)

for(j in 1:ncol(m)) myTIFF(m[1, j], m[2, j])
```

Note also that R has function called `dir` that automatically extracts the contents of a directory as a character vector, in the way that `ls` does for variables in the current environment. If you have a large number of CSV files, you can use this (possibly in conjunction with `grep`) to generate the matrix `m` programmatically rather than typing it by hand.

Comment: An alternative I just thought of would be to use `mapply`: `mapply(myTIFF, m[, 1], m[, 2])`. This might make more or less sense depending on the scenario.